# In React , why does the input field lose focus after typing a character?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i am using react Mui for components ,not getting any errors in chrome inspector or terminal
how can i slove this

I get no errors from either eslint nor Chrome Inspector.

Submitting the form itself works as does the actual input field when it is located either in the render's return or while being imported as a separate component but not in how I have it coded below.

Why is this so?
**Here is my code :**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Container,
  Stack,
  TextField,
  Typography,
  Button,
  Divider,
} from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const Register = () => {
  const Curve = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    height: "35vh",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: "100%",
    background: `linear-gradient(120deg,${theme.palette.secondary.light},${theme.palette.secondary.main})`,
    zIndex: -1,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: "30px",
    borderBottomRightRadius: "30px",
  }));
  const ProfileBox = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
    // margin: theme.spacing(18, 1),
    background: theme.palette.primary.dark,
    border: `solid 0.8px ${theme.palette.primary.light}`,
    borderRadius: "10px",
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  }));
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleRegister = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate("/");
  };

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    conpassword: "",
    phone: "",
    proffesion: "",
  });
  const [err, setErr] = useState({});
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    setValues(() => ({
      [id]: value,
    }));
    setValid(() => true);
  };

  const validate = () => {
    return setErr(checkErr());
    function checkErr() {
      const error = {};
      if (values.name.length === 0) error.name = "Name nedded";
      if (values.password.length === 0) error.password = "Password nedded";
      if (!values.email.match(/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/))
        error.email = "Invalid email";
      if (values.password.length < 6)
        error.password = "Password must be longer than 6 charectors";
      if (values.password !== values.conpassword)
        error.conpassword = "Password doesn't match";
      if (values.email.length === 0) error.email = "Email nedded";
      if (values.phone.length === 0) error.phone = "Phone number nedded";
      if (values.phone.length < 10) error.phone = "Invalid number";
      if (values.proffesion.length === 0)
        error.proffesion = "Proffesion nedded ex: lawyer ,student";
      return error;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm">
      <Curve></Curve>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "center",
          height: "30vh",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Typography variant="h6" algin="center">
          Register
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="caption" algin="center">
          your data is secured with us
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      <ProfileBox>
        <Stack spacing={2}>
          <TextField
            variant="standard"
            label="Name"
            color="secondary"
            value={values.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={validate}
            id="name"
            error={err.name}
            helperText={err.name}
          />
          <TextField
            type="email"
            variant="standard"
            label="Email"
            color="secondary"
            id="email"
            value={values.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={validate}
            error={err.email}
            helperText={err.email}
          />
          <TextField
            type="password"
            variant="standard"
            label="Password"
            color="secondary"
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={validate}
            id="password"
            error={err.password}
            helperText={err.password}
          />
          <TextField
            type="password"
            variant="standard"
            label="Conform password"
            color="secondary"
            value={values.conpassword}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={validate}
            id="conpassword"
            error={err.conpassword}
            helperText={err.conpassword}
          />
          <TextField
            type="tel"
            variant="standard"
            label="Phone"
            color="secondary"
            value={values.phone}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={validate}
            id="phone"
            error={err.phone}
            helperText={err.phone}
          />
          <TextField
            variant="standard"
            label="Proffestion"
            color="secondary"
            value={values.proffesion}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={validate}
            id="proffesion"
            error={err.proffesion}
            helperText={err.proffesion}
          />
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
            sx={{
              color: "primary.main",
            }}
            onClick={handleRegister}
          >
            Signup
          </Button>
          <Divider />
          <Typography variant="caption" algin="center">
            Allready have account{" "}
            <span>
              <Link to="/login" style={{ color: "var(--secondary)" }}>
                Login
              </Link>
            </span>
          </Typography>
        </Stack>
      </ProfileBox>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `handleChange` function like this:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    setValues(() => (prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        [id]: value,
      }
    }));
    setValid(true);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're creating components inside your `Register` component. This pattern is really bad for performance and prone to bugs exactly like your question.

On every type you're changing the state of the `Register` component, it re-renders itself, and re-creates `Curve` and `ProfileBox` from scratch, including their children (input fields). Which causes them to reset all their and their children's state, including focus.

You need to move `Curve` and `ProfileBox` outside of it, it will fix the issue.

```
const Curve = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  ... // the same
}));

const ProfileBox = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
 ... // the same
}));

const Register = () => {
```